# React Native Admob not working ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: admob, react-native, expo

I am trying to use react-native-admob. 
When I use Sample ad unit ID(ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716), then ad is showing. But when I change to  my own Ad unit ID, then ad does not show and gives error message:
**ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR**

```
<AdMobBanner
    bannerSize="fullBanner"
    adUnitID={BANNER_ID} 
    onDidFailToReceiveAdWithError={this.bannerError} 
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented Expo's Admob for iOS and Android. My experience is if you can show the test ad. You are good to go.

1. Android (emulator or device) test ad is buggy compared to iOS's. Ensure you have entered correct `adUnitID` is ok.
2. Set up your Payment Account in Admob if you haven't. After setup, it will kind of be fetching more accurate ad.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned by Calvin, you need to set up your payment account and wait up to 24h for it to be verified, then you'll start to be served ads on your unit id.